# Can something be "vapid of" something?

Tags: word-usage, government

The United States Department of Agriculture defines “food deserts” as “parts of the country *vapid of* fresh fruit, vegetables, and other healthful whole foods, usually found in impoverished areas” (emphasis added). Neither OED nor M-W defines *vapid* in a way that seems to fit this usage at all. Is this just yet another case of our federal government’s “cold-blooded murder of the English tongue,” or is this some usage that is gaining currency but that dictionaries have not yet caught up with?

P.S.: I draw a blank searching the actual usda.gov site for this definition, but it seems pretty widely quoted around the Web, including in [an issue of the American Nutrition Association newsletter from four or five years ago](http://americannutritionassociation.org/newsletter/usda-defines-food-deserts). Maybe the USDA corrected a usage error when it was pointed out to them.

Comment: I've never seen _vapid_ used that way. Perhaps they meant to use _vacant_?

Comment: I think it's just outright wrong- like someone who thought they knew what a word meant but really didn't.

Comment: Did autocorrect prevent someone from typing *devoid*?

Comment: Yeah, it's most likely a plain old mistake, due to someone attempting to sound a bit more highbrow than they really were -- perhaps, as Jeff suggests, reaching for "devoid" and grabbing "vapid" from their brain instead.  Not strongly indicative of a conspiracy.

Comment: The young heroes are consistently handsome and consistently ***vapid of expression.*** https://books.google.it/books?id=TLNkAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA269&dq=%22vapid+of%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=g95HVfSzKMuyUYC5gKAH&ved=0CF8Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22vapid%20of%22&f=false. The slow dragging on cigarettes, relaxed after the spent pleasure, supine on the blanket, ***the mind vapid of its jagged content, at rest***.  https://books.google.it/books?id=kSH9xGd2jOkC&pg=PA27&dq=%22vapid+of%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=hd9HVYLRM4PbUaHdgZgC&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAzgU#v=onepage&q=%22vapid%20of%22&f=false

Comment: (Unfortunately Ngram is not much help here, since there are phrases such as "the most vapid of all reading".)

Comment: The usage strikes me as a malapropism.

Comment: Vapid USDA and American Nutrition Association, I'd say.

Comment: @Drew Or *vacuous,* maybe.

Comment: Crazy bad English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with Jim and HotLicks that this is a misuse by someone who misunderstands the word and its use.

The two examples cited by Josh61 are instructive, and show how the misunderstanding might arise. The first is acceptable:

> The young heroes are ***vapid of expression***

Here the *of* phrase is a modifier telling us *what* is vapid: the heroes' expressions. It might in older English be paraphrased as *of vapid expression*, or in Present-Day English as *vapid **in** expression*.

But readers unfamiliar with the word might assume that the *of* phrase was complementary, as it is in *empty of X* or (as Jeff suggests) *devoid of X*. That would cause them to think that the collocation *vapid of X* explains what is lacking, and lead to misuses like your example, or Josh61's second one:

> the mind vapid of ... content

Answer (score 2):

A Google search turns up:

1. This page
2. The page the OP mentions
3. Someone saying "the most vapid of slogans"

I think it fair to say that everyone's intuition -- that the USDA example is just some bureaucrat mutilating the language -- is correct.